# How to get the type of page from url

Tags: magento-1.7, url-rewrite, category-products

Is there any methods to know which type of page i have with an url ?

I would like to know with a page .html if it s a product page , a category page , cms page or home ? 
And i would like to know also what is the productid, the categoryid, or the cms page id associate to the html url :)

Thanks a lot by advance

Thomas

Comment: In which location ?

Comment: hum for example i have this url : 
http://thomas.sandbox.upecom.com/robot-loisir/robots-jouets/interactifs.html
I would like a method which tell me : it s the category numer 3

Or
http://thomas.sandbox.upecom.com/spinmaster-zoomer-kitty-robot-chat.html
It as product page number 5

Do you see what i mean ? :)

Answer (score 1):

check product page and category page

```
   if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
        $id = $product->getId();
   }

   if(Mage::registry('current_category')){
      $category = Mage::registry('current_category');  
      $category->getId(); 
   }
```

Comment: @KeyurShah bro it was yesterday ,I enjoyed a lot with friends

Comment: Thanks Murtuza but i can t do that , indeed i will just send by ajax the url. So there is no current_.... :(

Comment: @thomaspoidevin can able to get Handlers ?? via this code `var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());`